# How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?

Tags: shell

grep returns

```
Binary file test.log matches
```

For example

```
echo    "line1 re \x00\r\nline2\r\nline3 re\r\n" > test.log  # in zsh
echo -e "line1 re \x00\r\nline2\r\nline3 re\r\n" > test.log  # in bash
grep re test.log
```

I wish the result will show line1 and line3 (total two lines).

Is it possible to use `tr` convert the unprintable data into readable data, to let grep work again?

Comment: Please note that there is a program that filters out binary characters from a binary file and keeps only the text characters (readable). Here: 
http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-words_extractor/index.html

Comment: Excuse me, but... aren't you missing `-e` in the `echo` command?

Comment: If you use 'zsh', it is ok without -e.  If you use 'bash', you should add '-e'.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/328101/how-do-i-grep-through-binary-files-that-look-like-text

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could run the data file through `cat -v`, e.g

```
$ cat -v tmp/test.log | grep re
line1 re ^@^M
line3 re^M
```

which could be then further post-processed to remove the junk; this is most analogous to your query about using `tr` for the task.

`-v` simply tells `cat` to display non-printing characters.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks! Here is what `man cat` says about `-v`: `-v, --show-nonprinting` `use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB`

Comment: Note that this works in a pipeline as well. E.g. `set | cat -v | grep variable`

Comment: Why use this if grep --text works?  This seems a lot more complex.

Comment: `grep --text` doesn't always work; it respects CTRL+D as a file terminator. So if you have that in your binary file, grep will exit early.

Answer (score 156):

```
grep -a
```

It can't get simpler than that.

Comment: this is the same as `grep --text` which [paxdiablo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9988534/829755) has mentioned 2 years earlier

Comment: Yes, except that this won't work on OSX unless you do the following: `LC_ALL="C" grep -a`

Comment: @ChrisStratton that was the GAME CHANGER answer! Thanks a lot. Could You elaborate on that a little bit more? Why You need to use this structure and what does it means?

Comment: C is the 'basic' locale/encoding, most other locales include more values as "plain text".

Answer (score 104):

One way is to simply treat binary files as text anyway, with `grep --text` but this may well result in binary information being sent to your terminal. That's not really a good idea if you're running a terminal that interprets the output stream (such as VT/DEC or many others).

Alternatively, you can send your file through `tr` with the following command:

```
tr '[\000-\011\013-\037\177-\377]' '.' <test.log | grep whatever
```

This will change anything less than a space character (except newline) and anything greater than 126, into a `.` character, leaving only the printables.

---

If you want every "illegal" character replaced by a different one, you can use something like the following C program, a classic standard input filter:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((ch == '\n') || ((ch >= ' ') && (ch <= '~'))) {
            putchar (ch);
        } else {
            printf ("{{%02x}}", ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will give you `{{NN}}`, where `NN` is the hex code for the character. You can simply adjust the `printf` for whatever style of output you want.

You can see that program in action here, where it:

```
pax$ printf 'Hello,\tBob\nGoodbye, Bob\n' | ./filterProg
Hello,{{09}}Bob
Goodbye, Bob
```

Comment: This method mapping all binary char into same '.' symbol.  Is there other method mapping them to readable symbols?

Comment: Sure, you can run it through a different filter program, one of which I've provided in an update.

Comment: I think `tr '[:cntrl:] '.'` is better.  And it should be `\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177-\377'` in your tr syntax.

Comment: After testing, `tr '[\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177-\377]' '_'` workable, the cntrl is not suitable for my case.

Comment: You can save the `cat` step by piping `grep --text` into `tr` instead of vice versa. This also lets you grep multiple files and keep the file name reference in the output.

Comment: @user55570, then I would suggest you download a copy of GNU tr and use it instead. Or switch to a better OS :-)

Answer (score 39):

You can use "strings" to extract strings from a binary file, for example

```
strings binary.file | grep foo
```

Comment: Worked well for me as the source was a debug log with UID on each line.  Thanks.

Comment: worked well for me too. Thanks for your answer. Saved my day :)

Comment: I appreciate @paxdiablo 's answer but for a quick answer and getting on with the job you cannot fault this.

Comment: Tried to use paxdiablo solution however it didn't give me any of the results I was expecting. @moodywoody your solution is quick, simple and outputs exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 21):

You can force grep to look at binary files with:

```
grep --binary-files=text
```

You might also want to add `-o` (`--only-matching`) so you don't get tons of binary gibberish that will bork your terminal.

Comment: might output binary garbage, which can have nasty side effects if the  output  is  a  terminal  and  if  the terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.

Comment: If you use `--only-matching`, and your regex does not match arbitrary binary data, you won't have a problem.

Comment: if the regular expression is 'first.*end' and the binary data contains in '.*' pattern, it can not correct process for my post processing.  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Starting with Grep 2.21, binary files are [treated differently](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8152):

> When searching binary data, grep now may treat non-text bytes as line
>   terminators. This can boost performance significantly.

So what happens now is that with binary data, all non-text bytes
(including newlines) are treated as line terminators. If you want to change this
behavior, you can:

- use `--text`. This will ensure that only newlines are line terminators
- use `--null-data`. This will ensure that only null bytes are line terminators

Answer (score 8):

grep -a will force grep to search and output from a file that grep thinks is binary. 
    grep -a re test.log

Answer (score 3):

As James Selvakumar already said, `grep -a` does the trick. -a or --text forces Grep to handle the inputstream as text.
See Manpage http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

try

```
cat test.log | grep -a somestring
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
strings test.log | grep -i
```

this will convert give output as a readable string to grep.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used in a system that didn't have "strings" command installed

```
cat yourfilename | tr -cd "[:print:]"
```

This prints the text and removes unprintable characters in one fell swoop, unlike "cat -v filename" which requires some postprocessing to remove unwanted stuff. Note that some of the binary data may be printable so you'll still get some gibberish between the good stuff. I think strings removes this gibberish too if you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Word Extractor](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-words_extractor/index.html) tool. Word Extractor can be used with any file in your computer to separate the strings that contain human text / words from binary code (exe applications, DLLs).

Comment: I my case, I don't require word extractor, I require to keep the line number.