# Difference between grep on a file and strings?

Tags: linux, string, grep, binaryfiles

I am searching for patterns in a binary file on linux, and am not sure if I should use the "grep" or "strings" command to parse the file. I can do:

```
grep *pattern* *file*
```

or

```
strings *file* | grep *pattern*
```

Which is more robust?

Comment: Neither is ideal. `grep` is a line-oriented tool, making it a poor choice for big binary blobs, but `strings` has known security bugs. It _will_, however, have the desired effect of extracting content in a form that `grep` can work with.

Comment: Are there other command line tools you might suggest?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: My understanding is that `strings -a` avoids the security bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, `cat --show-nonprinting` is better suited to this task

```
cat --show-nonprinting | grep pattern
```

Or

```
cat -v | grep pattern
```

[How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9988379/#10822566)

Comment: That behaves differently than the `strings` solution. `cat -v | grep` matches entire lines, which are delimited by `'\n'` characters (depending on the binary file, the entire file might be a single "line"). `strings` shows each contiguous group of printable characters on a separate line.

Comment: @KeithThompson pretty easy fix, `tr '[:cntrl:]' '\n'`, and if memory serves is still faster than strings